# Proving that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m > n$ from certain axioms

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

> For each $n \in\mathbb N$ there exists $m \in\mathbb N$ such that m > n.

Here are my axioms:

1. If $m,n \in\mathbb N$ then $m + n \in\mathbb N$
2. If $m,n \in\mathbb N$ then $mn \in\mathbb N$
3. $0 \notin\ \mathbb N$
4. For every $m \in\mathbb Z$, we have $m \in\mathbb N$ or $m = 0$ or $-m \in\mathbb N$

Definition: $m > n  = m - n \in\mathbb N$.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could please explain to me why this is. My strategy is to use a contradiction.

---

Here is another proposition that I have proven:

> For $m \in\mathbb Z$, one and only one of the following is true: $m \in\mathbb N$, $-m \in\mathbb N$, $m = 0$.

*Proof:* Let $m, n \in\mathbb N$, assume that $m - n \in\mathbb N$ is false, namely, 
$m - n \notin\mathbb N$. Given that addition is a binary operation, it will give a number $p \in\mathbb Z$. $m - n \notin\mathbb N$ holds if $-p \in\mathbb N$ or $p = 0$ (i.e. $0 \notin\mathbb N$) (axiom d). However, according to the proposition that I have proven, one and only one of the following is true: $m \in\mathbb N, -m \in\mathbb N, m = 0$. There is a contradiction. Thus, $m - n \in\mathbb N$ is true.

What do you think?

Comment: The final paragraph is not right. You should know it is wrong intuitively because at the start you merely assume $m$ and $n$ are in $\mathbb N$ and then proceed to "show" that $m > n$. Counterexample: choose $n = 2$, $m = 1$. The problem is there was really never any contradiction in your argument; you started with the assumption $m\in\mathbb N$, and that satisfies your "one and only one" theorem just fine.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you for your input. In my class, we have not yet seen any number that is natural. We simply have assumed that there exists a subset $N$ within $Z$. Hence, I am not allowed to use numbers. I assume the opposite and then try to show a contradiction from the axioms and the propositions. :) Could you suggest a different approach? Thank you!

Comment: I wasn't actually suggesting you write $1$ or $2$ in your proof. The counterexample was just a way for you to check your proof; it should be a tipoff that something is wrong if an argument shows that $1\in\mathbb N$ and $2\in\mathbb N$ implies $1 > 2$, even if you haven't actually constructed either of those numbers yet.

Comment: BTW, there should be a link to the previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1141649/139123 (and now there is). It's laudable that you're making multiple attempts at this rather than giving up.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you! :) I am being obsessed lol I really want to understand.

Comment: Question: can you prove that there exists something in $\Bbb N$?

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by $0\neq \mathbb N$

Comment: @Elaqqad Hi! It is an axiom: it means that zero is not a natural number (I wrote it wrong actually.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you refer to $\mathbb{Z}$ in your axiom d), I assume that $\mathbb{Z}$ is somehow "known" while $\mathbb{N}$ is not.

The first order of business is to prove that $1\in \mathbb{N}$. You can do this using your trichotomy axiom d), and arithmetic facts you know from $\mathbb{Z}$. Let me know if you need more hints.

Once you know $1\in \mathbb{N}$, for any given $n\in \mathbb{N}$, can you think of how to construct an $m$ with $m>n$ (using your definition of $>$)?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. Here is my strategy for proving that 1 $\in\mathbb N$:
Given m $\in\mathbb N$, $-m \notin\mathbb N$. $-m = (-1)m$. $-1$ is obviously not zero but isn't a natural number either because if it were, (-1)m would yield a natural number, which is not the case. A number is exclusively 0, natural, or non-natural. Hence, -1 is not natural. If you take the inverse of -1(i.e -(-m)), you get one which must be natural. What do you think? I am still thinking about the other proof. I'll get back to you! :)

Comment: Yes, this will work. You can also argue about 1 directly: since $1\neq 0$ (we know this from $\mathbb{Z}$) we must have that $1\in \mathbb{N}$ or $-1\in\mathbb{N}$. If the former, we are done. If the latter, then $-1\cdot -1=1$ must be a natural number after all.

Comment: I think I have the rest. Ok: so assume that $n \in\mathbb N$, I can construct another number $m \in\mathbb N$ by adding 1 to $n$. If $m > n$, then $m - n \in\mathbb N$. This is the case because $m - n = 1$. Hence, it is always possible to generate a natural number greater than another natural number. What do you think? Thank you!